# Use of join for these two datafrmaes in R or any other soln

Tags: r, join

i have data in 1 dataframe

```
Date       time     open  close 
1/1/2018   9.20am   100   105
1/1/2018   9.25am   106   108
1/1/2018   9.30am   109   111
1/1/2018   9.35am   110   112.5
1/1/2018   9.40am   112   115
1/2/2018   9.20am   116   118.9
1/2/2018   9.25am   118   120
1/2/2018   9.30am   115   117
1/2/2018   9.35am   118   120.5
1/2/2018   9.40am   115   119
1/3/2018   9.20am   118   116
1/3/2018   9.25am   116   114
1/3/2018   9.30am   113   117
1/3/2018   9.35am   118   120.5
1/3/2018   9.40am   118   111
```

another data frame has data like this

```
Date      rsi  macd
1/1/2018  50   20
1/2/2018  55   30
1/3/2018  40   33
```

i want my output to look like this

```
Date       time     open  close   rsi  macd
1/1/2018   9.20am   100   105     50   20
1/1/2018   9.25am   106   108     50   20 
1/1/2018   9.30am   109   111     50   20
1/1/2018   9.35am   110   112.5   50   20
1/1/2018   9.40am   112   115     50   20
1/2/2018   9.20am   116   118.9   55   30
1/2/2018   9.25am   118   120     55   30
1/2/2018   9.30am   115   117     55   30
1/2/2018   9.35am   118   120.5   55   30
1/2/2018   9.40am   115   119     55   30
1/3/2018   9.20am   118   116     40   33
1/3/2018   9.25am   116   114     40   33
1/3/2018   9.30am   113   117     40   33
1/3/2018   9.35am   118   120.5   40   33
1/3/2018   9.40am   118   111     40   33
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where x and y are your dataframes.

```
merge(x, y, by=c("Date"))
```